# cat/sed: concatenation of the fragments of the log filles

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cat

I have a folder consisted of many logs. Each log have a similar format.

This is the log1

```
Finding intermodel H-bonds
Finding intramodel H-bonds
Constraints relaxed by 0.55 angstroms and 40 degrees
Models used:
    1.1 SarsCov2_Y6A_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb

6 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
/? SER 144 OG   /d UNL 1 S     /? SER 144 HG    3.940  3.529
/? HIS 163 NE2  /d UNL 1 S     no hydrogen      3.821  N/A
/? GLN 189 NE2  /d UNL 1 O     /? GLN 189 1HE2  3.178  2.453
/d UNL 1 N      /? THR 25 OG1  /d UNL 1 HN      2.755  2.270
/d UNL 1 N      /? CYS 44 O    /d UNL 1 HN      3.277  2.501
/d UNL 1 N      /? ARG 188 O   /d UNL 1 HN      3.056  2.055
```

log2

```
Finding intermodel H-bonds
Finding intramodel H-bonds
Constraints relaxed by 0.55 angstroms and 40 degrees
Models used:
    1.1 SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb    
4 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
/? THR 26 N     /d UNL 1 O      /? THR 26 H      3.579  2.754
/? ASN 142 ND2  /d UNL 1 O      /? ASN 142 1HD2  3.250  2.324
/d UNL 1 N      /? THR 26 O     /d UNL 1 H       3.458  2.630
/d UNL 1 N      /? HIS 163 NE2  /d UNL 1 HN      3.222  2.456
```

This is the log 3:

```
Finding intermodel H-bonds
Finding intramodel H-bonds
Constraints relaxed by 0.55 angstroms and 40 degrees
Models used:
    1.1 SarsCov2_X7V_nsp5holo_rep1.pdb

2 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
/? GLN 189 NE2  /d UNL 1 O    /? GLN 189 1HE2  3.185  2.258
/d UNL 1 N      /? LEU 141 O  /d UNL 1 HN      2.868  1.958
```

I need to fuse all the logs together taking only the strings starting from # H-bonds adding the name of the initial file in the same line:

This is fused log produced by combining log1 -log 3:

```
log 1: 6 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
/? SER 144 OG   /d UNL 1 S     /? SER 144 HG    3.940  3.529
/? HIS 163 NE2  /d UNL 1 S     no hydrogen      3.821  N/A
/? GLN 189 NE2  /d UNL 1 O     /? GLN 189 1HE2  3.178  2.453
/d UNL 1 N      /? THR 25 OG1  /d UNL 1 HN      2.755  2.270
/d UNL 1 N      /? CYS 44 O    /d UNL 1 HN      3.277  2.501
/d UNL 1 N      /? ARG 188 O   /d UNL 1 HN      3.056  2.055


log 2: 4 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
/? THR 26 N     /d UNL 1 O      /? THR 26 H      3.579  2.754
/? ASN 142 ND2  /d UNL 1 O      /? ASN 142 1HD2  3.250  2.324
/d UNL 1 N      /? THR 26 O     /d UNL 1 H       3.458  2.630
/d UNL 1 N      /? HIS 163 NE2  /d UNL 1 HN      3.222  2.456

log3: 2 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
/? GLN 189 NE2  /d UNL 1 O    /? GLN 189 1HE2  3.185  2.258
/d UNL 1 N      /? LEU 141 O  /d UNL 1 HN      2.868  1.958
```

I've tried trivial solution with CAT but it does not work correcly since in each log I have different number of lines and TAIL could not recognize it correctly:

```
for log in ${results}/*_rep"${i}".log; do
  log_name=$(basename "$log" .log)
  echo "$log_name" >> ${results}/combined.log
  cat $log | tail -n 10 >> ${results}/combined.log
done
```

may I use cat in some specific expressin to recognize lines or alternatively I have to use SED before CAT to delete unused lines from each initial log ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk does the job:

```
awk '
FNR==1 {p=0}
/^[0-9]+[[:space:]]+H-bonds$/ && FNR!=NR {printf "\n"}
/^[0-9]+[[:space:]]+H-bonds$/ {printf "log %d: ", ++c; p=1}
p==1'
```

For each given file:

- Stop printing when each new file starts.
- If a line in the file matches a pattern for `4 H-bonds` etc, print an empty line break, if it's not the first file. Then print the log number, and set the flag `p` to begin printing that log file.
- Note that instead of testing for the same regex twice, you could omit the first one, and put `if (FNR!=NR) {printf "\n"}` inside the block of the second one. That's mainly about readability.
- I'm unsure which pattern expression you need for the file names, `*.log` is an example. Maybe `"${results}"/*_rep*.log`?

Comment: `print ""` is better than `printf "\n"` as it simply uses `ORS` rather  than  hard-coding the value that you hope `ORS` will be set to.

Comment: Rather than duplicating the main condition you could use `/^[0-9]+[[:space:]]+H-bonds$/ {if (FNR!=NR) print ""; printf "log %d: ", ++c; p=1}` or similar.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the feedback, I did mention the option of using an if statement in the third bullet point. Regarding the record separator, this was just about tidy formatting between paragraphs, I feel the explicit `\n` makes that intent clearer in this case. It also makes it easy for OP to choose a different separator string if desired (something like `\n-----\n` for example).

Answer (score 1):

**USE OF "F" FILENAME OPTION OF SED**

```
sed -i -n -s '1F;/[0-9] H-bonds/,$p' log* | sed -i -s '1N;s/\n/: /' log*
```

Explanation:
`-i` ---> inplace
`-n` ---> disable output
`-s` ----> treat all input file as seperate
`1F` ----> Print input filename for 1st line read
`/[0-9] H-bonds/,$p` ---> prints pattern range
`N;s/\n: /` ---> Merge first two lines adding :

Its a flaw in sed that "F" option directly output filename to stdout and not in pattern space and cannot play with it in one liner

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ for file in log{1..3}; do echo "${file##*/}: $(sed -n '/[0-9] H-bonds/,$p' "$file")"; echo ""; done
log1: 6 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
/? SER 144 OG   /d UNL 1 S     /? SER 144 HG    3.940  3.529
/? HIS 163 NE2  /d UNL 1 S     no hydrogen      3.821  N/A
/? GLN 189 NE2  /d UNL 1 O     /? GLN 189 1HE2  3.178  2.453
/d UNL 1 N      /? THR 25 OG1  /d UNL 1 HN      2.755  2.270
/d UNL 1 N      /? CYS 44 O    /d UNL 1 HN      3.277  2.501
/d UNL 1 N      /? ARG 188 O   /d UNL 1 HN      3.056  2.055

log2: 4 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
/? THR 26 N     /d UNL 1 O      /? THR 26 H      3.579  2.754
/? ASN 142 ND2  /d UNL 1 O      /? ASN 142 1HD2  3.250  2.324
/d UNL 1 N      /? THR 26 O     /d UNL 1 H       3.458  2.630
/d UNL 1 N      /? HIS 163 NE2  /d UNL 1 HN      3.222  2.456

log3: 2 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
/? GLN 189 NE2  /d UNL 1 O    /? GLN 189 1HE2  3.185  2.258
/d UNL 1 N      /? LEU 141 O  /d UNL 1 HN      2.868  1.958
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding the question, a simple grep seems to be what you are after:

```sh
grep -EH '^([0-9]+\s+)?H-bonds($| \()|^/' log*
```

Or if you need that **exact** format:

```sh
for log in log*; do
    sed -n "s/^[0-9]\+\s\+H-bonds$/$log: &/; /^$log: /,\${\$s/\$/\n/;p};" "$log"
done | sed '$d'
```

But I'm gonna guess the extra row break isn't necessary, and it then becomes simply:

```sh
for log in log*; do
    sed -n "s/^[0-9]\+\s\+H-bonds$/$log: &/; /^$log: /,\$p" "$log"
done
```

I'll happily return to edit this reply if extra explanation is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{f=0} /^[0-9]+ H-bonds/{$0=sep FILENAME": " $0; sep=ORS; f=1} f' log?
log1: 6 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
/? SER 144 OG   /d UNL 1 S     /? SER 144 HG    3.940  3.529
/? HIS 163 NE2  /d UNL 1 S     no hydrogen      3.821  N/A
/? GLN 189 NE2  /d UNL 1 O     /? GLN 189 1HE2  3.178  2.453
/d UNL 1 N      /? THR 25 OG1  /d UNL 1 HN      2.755  2.270
/d UNL 1 N      /? CYS 44 O    /d UNL 1 HN      3.277  2.501
/d UNL 1 N      /? ARG 188 O   /d UNL 1 HN      3.056  2.055

log2: 4 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
/? THR 26 N     /d UNL 1 O      /? THR 26 H      3.579  2.754
/? ASN 142 ND2  /d UNL 1 O      /? ASN 142 1HD2  3.250  2.324
/d UNL 1 N      /? THR 26 O     /d UNL 1 H       3.458  2.630
/d UNL 1 N      /? HIS 163 NE2  /d UNL 1 HN      3.222  2.456

log3: 2 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
/? GLN 189 NE2  /d UNL 1 O    /? GLN 189 1HE2  3.185  2.258
/d UNL 1 N      /? LEU 141 O  /d UNL 1 HN      2.868  1.958
```